# How to change button image for all UICollectionView cells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am using a `UICollectionView` to display some data. I am having one button on each cell. Now on the button click of at some specific index(ex: 9) I want to change buttons image for all cells. Can some one suggest how to do that?

Comment: yes you can do it with set selected flag for all collectionviewcell button image . and just reload your collectionview on button click.

Comment: Reload Your Collection View

Comment: You can set a boolean for identifying a button click and accordingly add logic for using Image. You can simply reload visible cells after that

Answer (score 1):

I would loop through all the visible cells and change the image. For example:

```
for (CustomCellClass *cell in collectionView.visibleCells) {
    [cell.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"new image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

For off-screen cells, I would make sure to set the new image in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` as the user scrolls to those cells.

Comment: why not just do them all in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` ?

Comment: Doing it like this means you don't have to reload the data.

Comment: This is better. Reloading data for all cells is not a better idea

Answer (score 0):

We can simply add the logic in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` like this.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

     if (self.buttonClicked) { // boolean check 
         [cell.newButton setImage:buttonClickedImage]; 
     }else {
         [cell.newButton setImage:buttonNotClickedImage];
     }

     return cell;
}
```

After clicking the button, you can also just reload all visible cells.

```
[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems];
```

Feel free to suggest edits to make this answer better :)